# What is the escape velocity of a Black Hole?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, escape-velocity

The escape velocity of Earth is $v=\sqrt{\frac {2GM}{R}}$, where $M$ is the mass of the Earth and $R$ it's radius (approximating it as a sphere), and is much less than light speed $c$.

But I want to know the escape velocity of black holes. Is it much more than light speed?

Comment: The escape velocity formula is $v_e=\sqrt{\frac {2GM}{R}}$

Comment: You might be interested in my response to [this related question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25369/why-cant-you-escape-a-black-hole), as it points out that escape velocities from black holes are not quite the same as Newtonian escape velocities.

Answer (score 12):

In General relativity, energy formula of a body thrown straight up to the infinity is

$\large {E=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-R_S/R}}}$

As we know relativistic energy formula is

$\large {E=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}}$

So

$\large {\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-v_e^2/c^2}}=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-R_S/R}}}$

hence escape velocity equation in General relativity is

${\large {v_e^2=c^2\frac{R_S}{R}}}$

where $R_S=2GM/c^2$ - Schwarzschild radius of a black hole, and $R>R_S$

It's easy to derive that

${\large {v_e=c\sqrt{\frac{R_S}{R}}}=\sqrt{\frac {2GM}{R}}}$

So escape velocity formula in  General relativity and Newton gravity is the same.

Comment: So the escape velocity at the event horizon would go to the speed of light as the ratio in the radical goes to 1?  Am I reading that right?  That would still quite simply imply infinite energy, so it seems consistent.

Comment: @AlanSE - Yes, for a point-like object.

Comment: I don't buy your derivation. The energy of a particle is not given by the second formula you've written since it neglects the gravitational field, you are considering a free particle. The [correct energy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Local_and_delayed_velocities) is $E=\gamma mc^2 \sqrt{1-2GM/R}$,  which leads to $v_e=\sqrt{2GM/R - (2GM/R)^2}$.

Comment: After coming back to this question, your answer is valid for a Schwarzschild BH when the escaping particle travels radially and you measuring the speed from the starting point. The formula I wrote assumes you measure the distance from a point at infinity, which is not the same since speed is coordinate dependent.

Comment: Is this only true for radial motion?

Answer (score 7):

The escape velocity from the surface (i.e., the event horizon) of a Black Hole is exactly $c$, the speed of light.

Actually the very prediction of the existence of black holes was based on the idea that there could be objects with escape velocity equal to $c$.

Comment: Where the "surface" is the event horizon. There isn't necessarily any material surface there.

Comment: Yes, that means event horizon.

Comment: But if the escape velocity is $c$, why can't light escape?

Comment: It can if it comes from a place just above the horizon. But it looses much of its energy and becomes redshifted.

Comment: There is no "the escape velocty". In GR, the escape velocity depends on the direction of launch.